# Can a prometheus vector be labeled?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have the following query:

```
(vector(1) and on() 
    rate(receiver_audio_track_bitrate{pod_name=~"$pod",session_id=~"$session"}[$__rate_interval]) == 0) 
    and on() (rate(sender_audio_track_bitrate{session_id=~"$session"}[$__rate_interval]) > 0)) 
or on() vector(0)
```

This query is intended to plot a scalar vector with a value of 1 if the receiver's audio track bitrate is zero while the sender's bitrate is non zero. Otherwise it will plot a scalar vector at 0.

The issue is that the scalar vector plotted does not contain the labels of `sender_audio_track_bitrate` and `receiver_audio_track_bitrate`. Is there any way to pass through the labels to the vector in this context?

Maybe there is an alternative approach to achieve my goal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following PromQL query instead:

```
rate(receiver_audio_track_bitrate{pod_name=~"$pod",session_id=~"$session"}[$__rate_interval]) ==bool 0)
  * on() group_left()
(rate(sender_audio_track_bitrate{session_id=~"$session"}[$__rate_interval]) >bool 0)
```

It uses `bool` modifier at [comparison operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators) for converting the results to `0` or `1`.

Comment: Thanks for the help @valyala! This answer definitely got me on the right path. I am still having some issues understanding why this query won't work with wildcard label matchers though. I asked a new, more detailed question on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74763085/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-prometheus-vector-matching-with-wildcard-label-ma). I'd appreciate any more insight you could provide!