# What is the correct way to use Prometheus vector matching with wildcard label matchers?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I am trying to match two metrics that have a one to many relationship. The first metric `webrtc_metrics_audio_outbound_rtp_bytes_sent` maps to many of the second metric `relay_node_audio_track_bytes`. That is to say that for each audio outbound rtp stream, there are many relay nodes consuming the stream. Each stream has a `session_id` that I'm trying to match across the metrics while also retaining the `pod_name` that is specific to each relay node.

I'm using comparison operators with bool modifiers as my intent is to set up an alert based on these two metrics. The alert should fire whenever there is non zero data for `webrtc_metrics_audio_outbound_rtp_bytes_sent` but corresponding zero data on `relay_node_audio_track_bytes` for the same `session_id`.

Here is my attempt using the following query and the corresponding output in Grafana:

```
((sum by (session_id, pod_name) (rate(relay_node_audio_track_bytes{pod_name=~"$pod",session_id=~"$session"}[$__rate_interval]))) == bool 0)
    * on (session_id) group_left(pod_name) 
((sum by (session_id) (label_replace(rate(webrtc_metrics_audio_outbound_rtp_bytes_sent{app="capturer",id=~"$session"}[$__rate_interval]), "session_id","$1","id","(.*)"))) > bool 0) > 0
```

You can see in the first graph when a `Pod` is selected in the dropdown, the query works as intended. But when I try to use a wildcard to query for all pods I receive there error: `execution: multiple matches for labels: grouping labels must ensure unique matches`

[image: OK query with Pod label matcher pinned]

[image]

Here are the left and right sides of the query showing all the labels in each metric. Note I used `label_replace` in the vector matching query to rename `id` to `session_id`.

LHS: `(rate(playback_relay_node_audio_track_bytes{pod_name=~"$pod",session_id=~"$session"}[$__rate_interval]))`

[image]

RHS: `label_replace(rate(webrtc_metrics_audio_outbound_rtp_bytes_sent{app="capturer",id=~"$session"}[$__rate_interval]), "session_id","$1","id","(.*)")`

[image]

Can somebody please explain why selecting a specific `Pod` does not throw the same error as when using a wildcard label matcher? Is there some other labeling methods I need to use to get this working as intended? Ideally I'd like to see this boolean condition plotted across all pods and session ids. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `pod_name` from `group_left()` modifier:

```
((sum by (session_id, pod_name) (rate(relay_node_audio_track_bytes{pod_name=~"$pod",session_id=~"$session"}[$__rate_interval]))) == bool 0)
    * on (session_id) group_left() 
((sum by (session_id) (label_replace(rate(webrtc_metrics_audio_outbound_rtp_bytes_sent{app="capturer",id=~"$session"}[$__rate_interval]), "session_id","$1","id","(.*)"))) > bool 0) > 0
```

Prometheus leaves all the labels from the left side after applying the `*` operator (or any other operator) if `group_left()` modifier is used. E.g. the original `pod_name` values from the left side are left in results after calculating the `*` with `group_left()` modifier.

The list of labels inside the `group_left()` modifier is taken from the matching time series on the right side of `*` . In this case time series returned from the right side of `*` have no the `pod_name` label. That's why the original values for this label obtained from the left side are substituted with empty values from the right side, e.g. they are effectively deleted. This may result in `duplicate time series` error when the same `session_id` value is present in multiple time series with different `pod_name` values at the left side of `*`.

See more details in [the official docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches).